# Show if the real polynomial $p(x) \neq nx$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, then there is no integer $m$ such that $p(x) +m\cdot2\pi = p(x+ 2\pi)$.

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, polynomials

Show that if the real polynomial $p(x) \neq 0, \pm x$, then there is no integer $m$ such that $p(x) +m\cdot(2\pi) = p(x+ 2\pi)$.

It seems harder than it looks. I'm quite stuck.

Comment: There are other polynomials, they are all of the form $mx$. Hint: What is the degree of $p(x+2\pi)-p(x)$ in terms of $\deg p(x)$? In the previous question, note that $\sin(mx)=m\sin x$ for $|m|>1$ would imply that $\sin$ takes values outside the range $[-1,1]$, impossible. Furthermore, an important caveat: note that $\sin(\alpha)=\sin(\beta)$ does not always imply $\alpha$ and $\beta$ differ by an integer multiple of $2\pi$; rather it implies that $\alpha$ is either $\beta$ or $\pi-\beta$ modulo integer multiples of $2\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the polynomial $f(x) = p(2\pi x)$.

We have $f(0) = p(0)$, $f(1) = p(2\pi) = 2 \pi m $, and more generally $f(n) = 2 \pi m n$ for all integers $n$.

**Hint:** Show that $f(x) = 2 \pi m x $ for all values of $x$.

Hence, $p(x) = mx$.

---

Now, if you are referring to your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/443998/find-all-real-polynomials-px-that-satisfy-sin-px-p-sinx) with solutions $p(x) = 0 \pm x$, then that is a different case.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $p(x) + m2\pi = p(x + 2\pi)$, and differentiate both sides with respect to $x$  (note that polynomials are always differentiable).  One obtains $p'(x) = p'(x+2\pi)$, which implies that derivative of $p$ is periodic.  Can you reason why this is impossible when $p$ is a nonlinear polynomial?